# How to create a 4-byte timestamp

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, unix-timestamp

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) uses a 4-byte timestamp in part of their objectID. Would I convert a timestamp into 4 bytes?

I think the piece that is missing is "BSON ObjectIds can be any 12 byte **binary**." So, I guess I'm looking to convert a timestamp to the first 4 binary pieces in :

[image]

Comment: It says exactly what it is on the page that you linked to. A 32 signed integer, that is the number of seconds since epoch. A unix time stamp. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something. Their example shows "47cc67093475061e3d95369d" the 47cc.. is not just an int like a timestamp (1338135513). I'm trying to figure out how to get 1338135513 into something like 47c...

Comment: You would be surprised what's an int. decimal isn't the only way to represent a number. [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) is a hint.

Comment: What driver are you using to connect to MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp *is* a 4 byte integer – it represents the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

What language are you using and what is it you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, my comment for 32bitkid was a little unclear. I meant the first part of the objectID is not just an int like a timestamp is an int. I am using c++ for this example

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper function to extract the timestamp as part of the API.

```
//OID ObjID; 
time_t ts = ObjID.asTimeT()
```

http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_o_i_d.html

Answer (score -1):

Parse the 4 bytes to a decimal with radix 16 and multiply by 1000.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.